# Event Handler Not Executing During Shopify Checkout

Tags: jquery, shopify

I am trying to execute some code when the Shopify checkout form is submitted but it is not firing.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $(document).on('submit', '.ajax-cart__cart-form', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default form submission

    alert('testing');

    if ($('#add-product-checkbox').is(':checked')) {
      // Use Shopify AJAX API to add the product to the cart
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/cart/add.js',
        data: {
          quantity: 1, // Adjust the quantity as needed
          id: 12345 // Variant ID of the product to add
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
          // Redirect the user to the checkout page
          window.location.href = '/checkout';
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          console.log('Error adding the product to the cart');
          console.log(textStatus);
        }
      });
    } else {
      // If the checkbox is not checked, proceed to the regular checkout
      window.location.href = '/checkout';
    }
  });    
  
});
```

Other jQuery code fires within the document.ready block but this doesn't get touched.